# Including 3rd Party Non-GitHub Libraries in GitHub

Tags: git, github

I have a project that I'm wanting to host in GitHub that includes several third-party libraries that are not hosted in GitHub (they're either in SVN or have no revision control whatsoever). Is it fine to just include the source of these libraries within my project (they're all open-source libraries) or is it a best practice to put the libraries in GitHub as a separate repository and then reference them?

Comment: What language is this project in?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you'll contribute or add features to the third lib that included, just '**put the libraries in GitHub as a separate repository and then reference them**' as you said. However, you ought  to check the lib existed on Github, if so, you can fork it as your own. And finally, make sure you reference them as `submodule`s. Open source organization will be thankful if you contribute to the lib.
Otherwise, just put the lib into your project with the copyright.